# I want to send data to the server and retrieve data from server to device

Tags: android

I am new learner of android app, I want to send data to the server and retrieve data from server to device , how can i do it ? and which server is best? thanks

Comment: You mean a database right, if so you can use sqlite. if this is not the case and you mean an actual server server then please explain your question a bit more.

Comment: There are no of questions related web service and samples available. Refer those. Search with "android web service sample".

Comment: Do you mean sending data from phone to webservice that will handle the data and store it to database ? If yes just use php webservice and httprequest

Answer (score 0):

i think You are asking for send data from android app to web server and received data from web Server.
 You can use php in server side and received post Or get method Parameter 
and while sending data to Phone use Json.
json is light weighted and easy to parse in android

Search google For RestAPI for Android app using Php

Answer (score 0):

You can use Network library to call server: (In this I used OkHttp3 library)

for request to server:

```
try {

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            String url = "url";


            MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM).addFormDataPart("key", value);



            MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(requestBody).build();
            Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

            data = response.body().string();
            Log.d("msg", "TIcket Data : " + data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
```

Now parse the data which you got from the server: (According to server response whether it's jsonobject or jsonarray or string)

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);

            Log.d("msg", jsonObject.toString());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
```